# Problems with strcpy and strcat

Tags: c++, c-strings

I just learned about the cstring and some functions in cstring library. When I tried to use the function strcpy, I got a confusing problem. Can anyone thoroughly explain to me why the first code doesn't work while the second one runs totally fine?

First code:

```
  char *str1 = "hello";
  char *str2 = "hi";
  strcpy(str1, str2);
  cout << str1;
```

Second code

```
   char str1[] = "hello";
   char *str2 = "hi";
   strcpy(s1,s2);
   cout << str1;
```

I guess the problem is how I declare the variable str1 but I still have no idea why it doesn't work when str1 is a pointer.

Comment: C++11 doesn't permit either because you're storing a string literal in a non-const `char*`. It's likely your compiler would warn/error if you turn those up.

Comment: Use `std::string` so you don't have to worry about it.  Also `char *str1 = "hello";` should be a compiler error/warning.  If you are not getting one you need to turn up the settings.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1704433/4926171) will answer your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, statement `char *str1 = "hello"` should give you a warning because you are assigning a pointer to string literal `"hello"` (which is `const`)  to non-const pointer `char* str1`. But if you wrote `const char *str1 = "hello"`, then the warning would disappear but you'd get an error with `strcpy`, because the first operand must not be `const`.

The second statement works because in `char str1[] = "hello"`, variable `str1` is actually an array (not a pointer), which is initialised with a let's say copy of `"hello"`. Hence, you are allowed to overwrite the contents of `str1` later on. Note that `str1` is not a pointer but an array; it rather decays to a pointer (to the memory of the first character of the array) when used in the context where a pointer is expected.

Comment: Please give a reason for downvoting such that the answer can be improved / corrected.